# Proof that $[\alpha, \beta]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I need to prove that $[\alpha, \beta]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ for $\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$. I think I almost completed the proof, but got stuck at the last step. Some hint(s) would be much appreciated.

**Proof:**

> We need to show that $[\alpha, \beta]^c=(-\infty, \alpha)\bigcup(\beta, \infty)$ is open. Let $x\in [\alpha, \beta]^c$, $\varepsilon_1=\lvert x_1-\beta\rvert$, $\varepsilon_2=\rvert x-\alpha\rvert$. Pick a $y\in B_\varepsilon(x)$, so that $\rvert y-x\rvert<\min\{\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2\}$. We need to show that $\rvert y- \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\rvert > \rvert\beta-\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\rvert=\rvert \frac{\beta - \alpha}{2} \rvert$.
>
> $\rvert y-\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\rvert = \rvert x-\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}-x+y\rvert \ge \rvert x- \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\rvert-\rvert x -y \rvert = \rvert x - \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\rvert-\rvert y-x\rvert > \rvert x-\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\rvert-\min\{\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2\}=\rvert x-\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\rvert-\rvert x-\beta \rvert$
>
> or $\rvert x-\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\rvert-\rvert x-\alpha \rvert$
>
> $\rvert x - \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\rvert-\rvert x-\beta\rvert \ge \rvert x \rvert - \rvert \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\rvert-\rvert x\rvert+\rvert\beta\rvert=\rvert\beta\rvert-\rvert \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\rvert...$

And that's where I get stuck.

Comment: Are you determined to prove it this way? Don't you have any previous results that you would be willing to use? The reason I ask is that it seems like it would be easier to prove that the union of two open sets is an open set, and that $(-\infty,\alpha)$ and $(\beta,\infty)$ are both open (this is just one easier way to prove what you want).

Comment: I think that the way you mentioned is the one I'm going to take. But I'm wondering if my attempt could be made into a complete proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove this without calculating so much, by noting that 
$$ B_\epsilon(x) = \{ y \in \mathbb R \, | \, \vert x - y \vert < \epsilon \} = (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon ) \; .$$

So let $\alpha < \beta$. We have $[\alpha, \beta]^{\mathrm c} = (-\infty, \alpha) \cup (\beta, \infty)$. Let $x \in [\alpha, \beta]^{\mathrm c}$. We need to show, that there is a $\epsilon > 0$, such that $B_\epsilon(x) \subset [\alpha, \beta]^{\mathrm c}$.
Let's assume that $x \in (-\infty, \alpha)$. We can choose an $\epsilon > 0$ with $0 < \epsilon < (\alpha - x)$. Then we have
$$B_\epsilon(x) = (x-\epsilon, x + \epsilon) \subset (x - \epsilon, \alpha) \subset (-\infty, \alpha) \subset [\alpha, \beta]^{\mathrm c} \; .$$

You can do basically the same thing if $x \in (\beta, \infty)$.